# Ubuntu 14, Postfix, Dovecat, Squirrle, Email messages not being sent to outside domains recipients

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have been suffering for so long from this..

All emails sent from the server are being delivered to local addresses.. but nothing to remote addresses!!

All emails are being received by local addresses whether sent locally or remotely!

The server is NOT able to deliver messages no matter what i change..

The server's FQDN is sub.domain.com
Hostname is sub.domain.com

Here the outputs .. PLEASE HELP!!!

## This is the telnet output:

```
root@mxl:~# telnet sub.domain.com 25
Trying ###.###.###.###...
Connected to sub.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 sub.domain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-sub.domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: mailuser@sub.domain.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: user@outsidedomain.com
454 4.7.1 <user@outsidedomain.com>: Relay access denied
```

## postconf -n

```
root@mxl:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = sub.domain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = sub.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions= permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

## postconf -Mf

```
root@mxl:~# postconf -Mf
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
    -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup     unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu
user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn
argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.
user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R
user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR
user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
${user}
root@mxl:~#
```

Comment: How can i be able to Send to OUTSIDE domains.. like gmail or yahoo?

Comment: Post the maillog entry when you send email outside

Comment: There you go @masegaloeh `Sep 23 09:44:38 mxl postfix/smtp[3058]: connect to outsidedomain.com[###.###.###.###]:25: Connection timed out
Sep 23 09:44:38 mxl postfix/smtp[3058]: B75E426097F: to=<user@outsidedomain.com>, relay=none, delay=36453, delays=36423/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to outsidedomain.com[###.###.###.###]:25: Connection timed out)`

Comment: Error message *Connection timed out* usually was a result of some firewall **blocks outgoing packet to port  25**. Try to talk you provider if they had that rules

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can't sent email from your ISP, might want to check out a smart host like sendgrid.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html

But, If you're sending out spam or have a compromised host, they'll block you too.